# Updating array list

Tags: java, arrays

Program is to take input from text file containing a player's number and stats. If a player is already in the list, I want to update that player's stats. I am having trouble with the method which determines if a player is already on the list. The current method prints all players regardless. Does the problem lie with my code in the main class or method?

```
public class Baseball8
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {

    Scanner fin = new Scanner(new FileReader("baseball.txt"));

    final int LIST_LENGTH = 20;

    int number = 0,         // number, hits, walks, outs
        hits = 0,
        walks = 0,
        outs = 0,
        players = 0,
        index = 0,
        teamSize = 0;
        playerIndex = 0;


    System.out.println("This program tracks a baseball player's number "
                         + "and their\number of walks, runs and outs for "
                         + "each game in a season.\n");


    Player team[] = new Player[LIST_LENGTH];

    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < LIST_LENGTH; i++)
        team[i] = new Player();



while (fin.hasNext())
    {
           number = fin.nextInt();
           hits = fin.nextInt();
           walks = fin.nextInt();
           outs = fin.nextInt();


        System.out.println(number + " " + hits + " " + walks + " " + outs + " ");



        playerIndex = findPlayerIndex(team,teamSize,number);


        if(playerIndex == -1)
        {
            team[teamSize].setNumber(number);
            team[teamSize].setHits(hits);
            team[teamSize].setWalks(walks);
            team[teamSize].setOuts(outs);
            teamSize++;
        }

        else
        {
            team[index].setHits(hits + team[index].getHits());
            team[index].setWalks(walks + team[index].getWalks());
            team[index].setOuts(outs + team[index].getOuts());
        }
   }
displayArray(team, teamSize);
fin.close();

}
```

.

```
public static int findPlayerIndex(Player p[], int n, int number)
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++);
    {
        if(p[i].getNumber() == number)
            return i;
       else
           return -1;
    }
}


    **Current output:**
//player hits, walks, outs are added to array[0]
     Player Hits    Walks   Outs
------  ----    -----   ----

 1   5  10  18     <
19   0   5   1
 2   0   0   6
18   4   2   0
 4   1   2   3
12   2   2   2
 7   0   0   3
 8   1   4   1
10   2   2   2
 3   2   1   3
11   6   0   0
17   4   2   0
 9   3   2   1


Desired output:
//stats added to array[i]
Player  Hits    Walks   Outs
------  ----    -----   ----

 1   2   2   2
19   0   5   7 <
 2   0   5   7
18   4   2   0
 4   3   3   6 <
12   2   2   2
 7   0   0   6 <
 8   1   4   1
10   2   2   2
 3   3   3   6 <
11   6   0   0
17   4   2   0
 9   3   2   1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems in your function **findPlayerIndex**

- remove ; after for so loop can work: for(i = 0; i < n; i++);  //remove **;**
- return -1 after loop finished, **int i** can declare in loop command. Like this:

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      if(p[i].getNumber() == number)
         return i;      
  }

  return -1;
  ```

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you, there are no longer duplicate players. Now I have to figure out how to add the stats properly.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to return `-1` after the loop rather than within the loop. i.e.

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
     if(p[i].getNumber() == number)
         return i;    
}
return -1;
```

This essentially ensures that you've checked the entire array and then if the predicate within the `for` loop is not met then `-1` will be returned.

Comment: I understand why it should return -1 outside of the loop, otherwise it returns regardless. However, I still get the same output. A friend suggested updating the return type to void in the method, but that doesn't seem appropriate.

Comment: well, you mentioned _I am having trouble with the method which determines if a player is already on the list._ hence I've suggested an answer to it. Nevertheless please show the current result you're getting and the expected result, also show all the code necessary.

Comment: I was just trying to show that I follow your explanation. I am updating the original question to include current and desired output.

Comment: including the array declaration and variables initialized.

Comment: @bap you mentioned that _The current method prints all players regardless._ that's because of your `displayArray` prints all of them out. what data do you want that method to print?

Comment: I want to display all of the players once, all duplicate players stats are to be added and displayed as one output. For example, players 3,4,7, and 19 come up twice.